# How to create and write a properties file using shell script

Tags: shell, properties, sh

I have a shell file and in that I need to create and write a content as below into my abc.properties file.

version=123456-> This is the one thing which is required in my properties file.

I tried with the below commands and its not writing the contents into the file.

```
sh "touch abc.properties"
sh "lscm show lastmod . -f yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS >> ${lscm_home}/abc.properties"
```

Can someone provide some inputs on how can i make the second command to write into the required file ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below

> echo "Version=`lscm show lastmod . -f yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS`" >> FILE_NAME

Comment: If I give like this it is simply printing which is present inside echo statement. And when trying to write into my file, it shows the error as "Log out action failed : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: version for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

Comment: Hi, I have update the command. Please try again